# Exposing (PostGIS) spatial operations as web services?

Tags: postgis, web-service

How can (PostGIS) spatial operations be exposed as web services?

e.g. if we wanted a web service end point that would return a data set with the top 5 schools nearest to a location

**NOTE:** can I make it clear that this is **NOT** for presentation on a map. Rather it is for use in a server-side workflow, where next stages in the workflow will be using the list of schools for additional actions.

*I could write a .NET WCF web service, and maybe somehow call the PostGIS system, but this seems a bit overkill. And I seriously can't believe we're the first place that wants to do this.*

Comment: I don't see how that would be "overkill." You need a web service with some SQL calls inside of it -- it couldn't be simpler. For the example you gave, you can just pass the x and y in a query string and make the DB call directly. No need to even work with spatial objects.

Comment: @RobSkelly I'm more than happy to write the code, but other people in the team are not C# developers, so I was hoping for something more "off the shelf" that they can use. Plus writing a web service for every query doesn't sound very sustainable

Comment: Oh, I see. Fair enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response is obviously yes and there is probably a bunch of good solutions.

Picking a favorite one with [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/), for example:

1. create a sql function with "location point" as parameters witch
   returns  5 rows (nearest schools) using `order by st_distance` and `limit 5`
2. create a [geoserver sql view](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) and use your above pg function;
3. Use [WFS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) queries;

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) and the [Web Processing Service (WPS) extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/extensions/wps/index.html). This would allow the use of arbitrary workflows constructed from the existing processes (things like buffering, filtering etc) and new processes constructed in Java using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org).

If you prefer python there is [PyWPS](http://pywps.org/) or [ZooWPS](http://www.zoo-project.org/) which have similar capabilities and an identical interface so switching between the different services would have no effect on your other workflows.

Comment: Anything for .NET and C#

Comment: Wikipedia points to https://code.google.com/archive/p/wps-net/

Comment: Looks to be a dead project ... last commit was in 2012

Comment: That was when Google code closed, I think. Wps. Net is hard to Google for :-(